# Hashtable an item with the same key has already been added ArgumentException

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
    private User LoadData(uint userID)
    {

        User data = null;
        DataRow dRow;
        DataTable group = new DataTable();  

        //nonrelevant MySQL queries here.

        data = UserFactory.GenerateUser(dRow, group);
        while (loadedUserData.Contains(userID))
            loadedUserData.Remove(userID);
        if (!loadedUserData.ContainsKey(userID))
            loadedUserData.Add(userID, data);
        return data;
    }
```

I'm getting ArgumentException exceptions of for example:

```
Item has been already added. Key in the dictionary: '370674'  Key added: '370674'
```

I can't seem to find what the error is. I have tried many things and none of them work. As you can see theres already a check, and the entry shouldn't be added.

Comment: Why not use a setter to do it: loadedUserData[userID] = data; it will take care of add/replace scenario?

Comment: step through in the debugger....

Comment: Well, thats embarrassing. I should have thought about that @AlexeyRaga, thanks. PD: put it as an answer.